# Setting PATH for R calling gdal_calc.py in Windows

Tags: r, windows, gdal

I am looking for advice on how to install R 4.2.1 and GDAL on Windows 10.
This is a work machine that the IT department manages, but they are not sure how to proceed.
The machine has:
R4.2.1, Rtools 42, and GDAL (installed from OSGeo4W last week).

When I open R, I can install sf and terra, but when I type system("gdal_calc.py --help", intern = TRUE) I receive file not found.
I am using a package (currently private) that requires the gdal_calc.py, and so I am unable to run my computations.

IT has changed the PATH variables manually within Windows to the following:

```
C:\rtools42\mingw32\bin;
C:\rtools42\bin;
C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin;
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\saga;
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\saga\modules;
%PYTHONHOME%;
C:\OSGeo4W\bin;
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis;
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass83\bin;
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass83\scripts;
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass83\lib;
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\gdal;
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\gdal-dev;
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\python.exe;
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Scripts\gdal_calc.py;
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\;
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Scripts\;
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
```

It did not help. I tried googling the issue but could not find any other suggestion.

Is there an error in the way the PATHs were set?
Do you have any advice on something the IT could try?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you confirm that R sees your `PATH` changes? If not, try changing it within R itself (`Sys.setenv(PATH=...)`) and try again.

Comment: I do not know what you use `gdal_calc.py` for, but such loose coupling with a system requirement is always going to be a pain. Can't you use the same functionality via the "terra" package?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I checked the `Sys.getenv("PATH")` from R, and it's correct. I have given up and now using "terra' directly, which is working. The downside is that the computing time is much slower. Thanks again!